# How do I display the date in the Long Date Pattern when the user inputs the date as yymmdd in a C# console application?

Tags: c#

```
Console.write("Enter date:");
string sDate = Console.ReadLine();
```

Let's say the user entered `990601`.

The output should be:

```
Tuesday 01 June 1999
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user's input date format is always `YYMMDD`, you can use [`ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(sDate, "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.write(myDate.ToLongDateString());
```

Comment: your missing the `ToLongDateString()` as the question requested :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.Write(DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToLongDateString());
```